# Scala: multiple return statement in method that returns Future[Boolean]

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I want to do something like this.

```
 def foo(s : String): Future[Boolean] = Future {
    val a = someLongRunningMethod

    if(!a)
      return false or throw some exception // what should i return 

    //do some more thing

    val b= someMoreLongRunningMethod
    if(b)
      return true

    return false
  }
```

but not able to use return with boolean. I got type mismatch error.

```
Error:(32, 12) type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean(false)
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[Boolean]
    return false
```

I am new to Scala. I am using foo method as this. I am not sure if it's the best way to use it. Please suggest how should i achieve it ?

```
val r = foo("Nishant")
r.onComplete {
  case Success(result) => {
    //Do something with my list
    println("success: " + result)
  }
  case Failure(exception) => {
    //Do something with my error
    println("failure")
  }
}
val re = Await.result(r, 10 second)
```

Comment: You need to first read a tutorial about how the `Future` type is working (btw using such return is not Scala idomatic)

Comment: http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Comment: i read some tutorial but all of them have example with single if/else block. can you suggest some good tutorial

Answer (score 2):

> In Scala last expression in the block is the return value of the codeblock or function. Keyword return is optional in scala.

Notice that we run second task only if one task returns true. If first task returns false then we are done. That means first task is really important for our computation as its the decision maker.

Your version modified:

```
  def longRunning1: Boolean = ???
  def longRunning2: Boolean = ???

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def foo(s : String): Future[Boolean] = Future {
    val a: Boolean = longRunning1
    if(a) {
      val b: Boolean = longRunning2
      b
    } else false
  }
```

Version 1:

Run futures (computations or long running methods) simultaneously and choose the results later. Here we discard the result of the second computation if we consider or want the result of the first computation.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def foo(s: String): Future[Boolean] = {

    val f1 = Future {
      Thread.sleep(20000) //Just to simulate long running task
      Random.nextBoolean()
    }

    val f2 = Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000) //Just to simulate long running task
      Random.nextBoolean()
    }

    (f1 zip f2) map {
      case (false, _) => false
      case (true, f2Result) => f2Result
      case _ => false
    }

  }
```

Version 2:

Run first method and then based on the result of the first method try to run the second method one after other. Computation is chained using map.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def foo(s: String): Future[Boolean] = {

    val f1 = Future {
      Thread.sleep(20000) //Just to simulate long running task
      Random.nextBoolean()
    }

    f1.map { result =>
      if (result) result
      else {
        Thread.sleep(1000) //Just to simulate long running task
        Random.nextBoolean()
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: In Version 2..how to handle exceptions if both logRunningTash can throw and which one is better when both tasks are dependent i.e. second one required input from first one?

Comment: @NishantKumar let me update the question with exception cases

Comment: @NishantKumar version: 2 is better than version 1. From exception point of view both v1 and v2 are good